# Why does not googlebot crawl my website?

Tags: seo, googlebot

I create some websites and ping them to google using pingomatic. Some websites are soon indexed by google, but others are not indexed at all(site: does not return any result). Note that this is not due to the content of the websites because I checked the access log of the websites and did not find googlebot at all. I repeat pinging several times on different days but it does not work. I wonder why googlebot does not find my websites. Are there other ways except pingomatic and google search console that can help googlebot to find my websites?

Comment: How long has it been since these websites have been created?

Comment: I created and pinged the website more than a week ago.

Comment: Crawling is not the same as indexing.   Googlebot often crawls pages and decides not to index them.   If you want to see if something has been crawled you have to look for Googlebot hits in your access log file on your web server.    A `site:` query will only tell you about things that are indexed.    When you are asking why your pages don't appear in Google, you are asking why Google is not indexing your content.

Comment: Without the additional off site methods I've indicated in my answer, it could take several weeks, even a month, for Googlebot to crawl/index your websites. Especially since they are new. This is normal.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller please do not close my question. I'm asking why googlebot does not crawl my website, not why google does not index my website.

Comment: Then please edit your question to remove site colon information and tell how you looked for googlebot crawling in your logs instead.

Answer (score 2):

There could be many reasons why Googlebot has not crawled your website(s) yet.
It could be because of the topics of your content, it could be how your website is configured, or it could be that it just hasn't found it yet.

Here are some things that you check to narrow down the possibilities:

1. You have a sitemap that is reachable and submitted in Google Search Console
2. Your Robots.txt file is not disallowing bots (or at least just not Googlebot)
3. Your web pages do not contain robots meta `noindex` tags
4. Your SSL Certificate is valid and that SSL/TLS is working properly

One *off site* strategy that can be effective in helping Google find your website faster is by **building links to it**.

You don't have to *all out* link build (like via content strategy, outreach, etc)  to accomplish this - submitting it to popular directories or listing it in your profiles on other websites will work just as well.

If your site is for your business, creating a Google My Business profile will help too.